# Chrome in lambda layers not found by lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

[image]I'm getting started trying to write a lambda function with node and puppeteer. I'm using the serverless framework

I've been trying to follow directions at https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda. My function is working as expected locally, with:

```
$ sls invoke local -f hello
```

working as expected. However when I run:

```
$ sls invoke -f hello
```

I get:

```
$ sls invoke  -f hello
{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'chr'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/task/handler.js\n- /var/task/s_hello.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"trace": [
    "Error: Cannot find module 'chr'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/task/handler.js",
    "- /var/task/s_hello.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)",
    "    at Module._require.o.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:72748)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)",
    "    at Object.main (/var/task/index.js:47:26)",
    "    at module.exports.hello (/var/task/handler.js:6:25)",
    "    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:137040)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
]
```

How can I get this working?

My handler.js contains:

```
'use strict';
var index = require('./index.js');

module.exports.hello = async event => {
// var t = async event => {
  var res = await index.main();

  console.log('hello');
  console.log(res);

  console.log('IN HANDLER');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: 'main function executed!',
        input: event,
     ......
```

my index.js contains:

```
async function main(event, context, callback) {

  const os = require('os');

  let result = null;
  let browser = null;

if (os.platform=='win32') {

  const puppeteer= require('puppeteer-core');
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors:true
  })
} else {
// launch a headless browser

  const chromeLambda = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
console.log(os.platform());  
console.log('lambda');  
browser = await chromeLambda.puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromeLambda.args,
    executablePath: await chromeLambda.executablePath,
    defaultViewport,
    headless:true 
  });





  var page = await browser.newPage();

   ........

};


module.exports.main = main;
```

package.json:

```
  "license": "ISC",
```

"dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^3.1.1",
    "puppeteer-core": "^3.1.0"

```
}
```

serverless.yml:

```
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
.......
# Happy Coding!
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
service: xxxxx
# app and org for use with dashboard.serverless.com
app: yyyyy
org: xxxx

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  # here we put the layers we want to use
  layers:
# Google Chrome for AWS Lambda as a layer
# Make sure you use the latest version depending on the region
# https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer
    - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:764866452798:layer:chrome-aws-lambda:10
    - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:155754363046:layer:chr:1

.....

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
  # main:
    # handler: handler.main
#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
    events:
     - http:
         path: hello/get
         method: get

.....
```

Comment: Did you make "proper" folder structure for your layer ? such as `nodejs/nodel_modules/chrome-aws-lambda` ?

Comment: @Ersoy ,  I don't understand what you mean by 'proper'.

Comment: There are conventions for lambda layers, the name of folder should follow this convention to inject/use layers